# Magento : In Controller get POST data and that data added to pdf file after attachment send mail

Tags: magento-1.9, email, pdf

In Magento, while submit form from frontend in controller using post method i got every data. I want create one pdf file and keep this data in it after that attachment of this file and send with mail.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Use TCPDF file for generate PDF.

How to use TCPDF in magento [Go Here](http://www.ashrafulabedein.com/use-tcpdf-magento/)

Create one custom phtml file in your theme direactory and generate output to print it in tcpdf.

call it in you controller file like this

```
$htmlContent = $this->getLayout()->createBlock('core/template')->setPostData($data)->setTemplate('<your template file>');
```

and in your template file you can get your post data like

```
$this->getPostData()
```

attached generated pdf with mail.

**Edit**

generate pdf in the media directory with post data and send it using below code.

change code according to your variable and need.

```
        $mailer = Mage::getModel('core/email_template_mailer');

    $emailInfo = Mage::getModel('core/email_info');
    $emailInfo->addTo($to, $customerName);
    $mailer->addEmailInfo($emailInfo);

    $mailer->setSender('test@gmail.com');
    $mailer->setStoreId(1);
    $mailer->setTemplateId(2);

    $filePath = $mediaDir.DS.$uploadedfilePath;
    $_pdfSavePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media').DS.'pdf_order_template';
    if(file_exists($filePath)){
         $pdfContent  = file_get_contents($filePath);
        $mailer->addPDFAttachment($pdfContent,  'Order_PDF-' . $order->getIncrementId() .  '.pdf');
     }

       $mailer->send();
```

Comment: Have you any example of that ? i want to add post data into pdf file and send it with mail  using controller.

Comment: code added for mail with attachement

Comment: Please check new answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this code:

```
public function sendemailAction()
{    
      $request     = $this->getRequest()->getPost();
      $mail   = Mage::getModel('core/email');           
            $content = '<h2>Personal Information</h2><br>';
            $content .= '<label>Name:</label>'.$request['name'].'<br>';
            $content .= '<label>Email:</label>'.$request['email'].'<br>';  
    require_once(Mage::getBaseDir('lib') . DS . 'TCPDF-master/examples/tcpdf_include.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
            // set document information
            $pdf->SetCreator(PDF_CREATOR);
            $pdf->SetAuthor('Asmani');
            $pdf->SetTitle('TCPDF Example GJ01');
            $pdf->SetSubject('TCPDF Tutorial');
            $pdf->SetKeywords('TCPDF, PDF, example, test, guide');

            $pdf->writeHTMLCell(0, 0, '', '', $content, 0, 1, 0, true, '', true);
            $pdf->Output('example_001.pdf', 'I');
$to = 'xyz@gmail.com';

            $mail->setBody($body);
            $mail->setFromEmail($fromemail);
            $mail->setFromName($request['name']);
            $mail->setToEmail($to);
            $mail->setSubject('Review Form');
            $mail->setType('html');
            try {
                $mail->send();               

            }
            catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::getSingleton('core/session')->addError('Unable to send.');
            }
```

but still not working for me.
Got 500 error.